# Agent inside of an agent-container

Tags: anylogic

I am new to Anylogic and I have a question, how do I find the agent in the agent-container?

The goal is: I have details that go on a pallet (1 detail on 1 pallet), depending on which detail is on the pallet, I need to select the path (in the SelectOutput block).
The pallet and the parts (k1 to k3) are different agents.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfiXL.png)

I tried using "instanceof". I've read that .contents() should give me what's inside the agent-container, but the  "agent.contents() instanceof k1" doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`agent.contents()` returns a list of agents. You cannot ask a list of agents if it is `instance of K1`.

Instead, you need to decide which agent of the contents to check for.

One solution: Check the first: `agent.contents().get(0) instanceof K1` should work.

But it is up to you to figure out which content agent to check, or all of them, or else...

Better approach may be to create a variable `myAgent` in the Pallet agent and fill it when the pallet is filled. Then just refer to that instead of `agent.contents()`